# 'Operation has been canceled' while adding a new accessory to HomeKit app

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, homekit

I'm developing a SwiftUI app for iOS and iPadOS to control my HomeKit smart devices, especially a RGB led strip. I have downloaded the accessory simulator and I have created two accessories named "Plug" and "Led Strip". I'm following [this official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/homekit/configuring_a_home_automation_device) and I was able to create and to remove new homes using this code:

```
class HomeStore: NSObject {
    static var shared = HomeStore()
    let homeManager = HMHomeManager()
    var homeDelegates = Set<NSObject>()
    var accessoryDelegates = Set<NSObject>()
}

extension HomeStore: HMHomeManagerDelegate {
    func addHome(name: String) {
        homeManager.addHome(withName: name, completionHandler: { (home, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error while adding a new home named \(name): \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    })
}

func removeHome(homeName: String) {
    homeManager.homes.forEach({ home in
        if (home.name == homeName) {
            homeManager.removeHome(home, completionHandler: { error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error while removing home named \(homeName): \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

I created another function to search new accessories:

```
func searchAccessories() -> [HMAccessory] {
    accessoryBrowser.startSearchingForNewAccessories()
    accessoryBrowser.stopSearchingForNewAccessories()
    return accessoryBrowser.discoveredAccessories
}
```

If I run this function above it searches for new accessories and show me them in this SwiftUI View:

```
var body: some View {
    Form {
        ForEach(homeStore.searchAccessories()) { accessory in
            Section {
                Text(accessory.name)
                Button("Add", action: {
                    homeStore.addAccessory(accessory: accessory, to: home)
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: SwiftUI View]

When I press on "Add" button it runs the following function:

```
func addAccessory(home: HMHome, accessory: HMAccessory) {
    home.addAccessory(accessory, completionHandler: { error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error while adding a new accessory named \(accessory.name) to home \(home.name): \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    })
}
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
Error while adding a new accessory named Led Strip to home Casa: Object not found.
```

I tried also adding manually HomeKit-URL (of the type X-ME://ect..) with the following function:

```
func addAccessory(name: String, to home: HMHome, to room: HMRoom, url: URL) {
    let request = HMAccessorySetupRequest()
    request.suggestedAccessoryName = name
    request.homeUniqueIdentifier = home.uniqueIdentifier
    request.suggestedRoomUniqueIdentifier = room.uniqueIdentifier
    request.payload = HMAccessorySetupPayload(url: url)

    let setupManager = HMAccessorySetupManager()
    setupManager.performAccessorySetup(using: request, completionHandler: { result, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error while adding accessory named \(name) to home \(home.name), room \(room.name): \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    })
}
```

But it gives me error 17: insufficient privileges for the operation.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue by following the tutorial on Raywenderlich.

Comment: I made an hybrid version of the tutorial on Raywenderlich and the official Apple documentation but it doesn't work

Comment: At this point I think it's better to try posting this issue in the Apple developer forum. Or looking if there is a repository on GitHub that has a working implementation of HomeKit.

Comment: I have already asked on Apple Developer Forum and I received no answer. You can find my post at this [link](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/713442). I'm searching for a github repository me too. If you find one get me know.

Answer (score 0):

so this could be because you haven't downloaded the `HomeKit Simulator` there's an apple doc [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/homekit/testing_your_app_with_the_homekit_accessory_simulator) on how to do that. It essentially aids in developing and testing HomeKit Accessories.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have already downloaded the HomeKit Simulator and I created an accessory. I tried to add it manually using [this class](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/homekit/hmaccessorysetupmanager) and QR code but it gives me Error 17 that means "insufficient privileges for the operation".

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply. I've been looking for a tutorial for a working implementation of HomeKit in iOS for several months and **I finally found it!**

I was able to create a working HomeKit app with SwiftUI by following [this article](https://www.createwithswift.com/creating-a-homekit-enabled-app-with-swiftui/). The only thing to consider is that it requires a paid subscription to see the full article.